# How to implement 'search function' for Mailboxer's each box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Now I'm using a gem called 'mailboxer' for messaging system.https://github.com/ging/mailboxer
I'd like to implement 'keyword search function' for inbox, sentbox, and trash.

If I don't care about search keyword, it is fetching the result without any problem by coding like this

```
inbox...   @messages = current_user.mailbox.inbox.page(params[:page]).per(10)
sentbox... @messages = current_user.mailbox.sentbox.page(params[:page]).per(10)    
trash...   @messages = current_user.mailbox.trash.page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

But I sometimes want to filter the result with search keyword.
Assume search keyword was 'test' this time, the result should be only the records that contain 'test' within body attribute in notifications table.
How can I do this for each above such as inbox, sentbox, and trash??

I tried this but it didn't work at all :(

```
@messages = current_user.mailbox.inbox.search_messages(@search).page(params[:page]).per(10)
@messages = current_user.mailbox.sentbox.search_messages(@search).page(params[:page]).per(10)
@messages = current_user.mailbox.trash.search_messages(@search).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

Comment: Have you implement the search functionality if yes then please let me know as i have to achieve the same functionality. I have followed the github but it didn't work ....

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to monkey patch both the Mailboxer::Receipt and Mailboxer::Models::Messageable module to enable searching by box type:

```
class Mailboxer::Receipt < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  if Mailboxer.search_enabled
    searchable do
      text :subject, :boost => 5 do
        message.subject if message
      end
      text :body do
        message.body if message
      end
      integer :receiver_id

      # Add mailbox_type to sunspot search field
      string  :mailbox_type
      boolean :trashed
      boolean :deleted
    end
  end
end
```

and under the Messageable module, I've added new search__messages method for each mailbox type:

```
module Mailboxer
  module Models
    module Messageable

      def search_messages(query)

        # Replaces 'search' with alias 'solr_search' since ransack search clashes with solr search method
        @search = Mailboxer::Receipt.solr_search do
          fulltext query
          with :receiver_id, self.id
        end

        @search.results.map { |r| r.conversation }.uniq
      end

      # Adds additional Mailboxer search functionality to search by box type
      def search_inbox_messages(query)
        @search = Mailboxer::Receipt.solr_search do
          fulltext query
          with :receiver_id, self.id
          with(:mailbox_type).equal_to("inbox")
        end

        @search.results.map { |r| r.conversation }.uniq
      end

      def search_sent_messages(query)
        @search = Mailboxer::Receipt.solr_search do
          fulltext query
          with :receiver_id, self.id
          with(:mailbox_type).equal_to("sentbox")
        end

        @search.results.map { |r| r.conversation }.uniq
      end

      def search_trash_messages(query)
        @search = Mailboxer::Receipt.solr_search do
          fulltext query
          with :receiver_id, self.id
          with :trashed, true
          with :deleted, false
        end

        @search.results.map { |r| r.conversation }.uniq
      end

    end
  end
end
```

With this, in your controller you can simply use the newly defined methods to do the box type searching.

```
current_user.search_inbox_messages(query[:keywords])
current_user.search_sentbox_messages(query[:keywords])
current_user.search_trash_messages(query[:keywords])
```

IMPORTANT NOTE: Make sure to regenerate the Solr indexes after adding the new search fields, otherwise nothing will show up:

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex
```

Hope this helps!